# Unable to use apache commons ftp import

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, import, ftp

I've been trying to create my own FTP client written in Java. I wrote one ages ago in C#, so I would like to try in Java. I created a user library for apache commons and added it to my build path. The problem is that when typing the import statement it doesn't recognise it. It finds a error at org, saying "import org cannot be resolved".

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
```

I am using eclipse as my IDE.

Here two screenshots showing the error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show the added library in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_ (instead of adding it as user library, you could have added it also directly as JAR or external library, but it should work either way).

Comment: I have the JRE library and I added the apache-commons to my project library

Comment: Please add a screenshot of that dialog to your question. I guess, there are errors in the _Problems_ view. If there are build errors, please add also the error messages to your question.

Comment: I can't post images yet. How do you want me to link the screenshots? (Which site?)

Comment: You can copy the error message(s) as text. If you add a link to the screenshot, I will embed it as an image for you (I was not aware of this limitation).

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/mZf0u7f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **following line** is probably missing **in the `module-info.java`** file:

```
requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
```

and in the *Java Build Path* the *Classpath* contains the broken (as you can see from the red error mark) item `apache-commons-lang` by mistake: select it and click *Remove*.

Since Java 9, modules can be specified, but this requires a correct `module-info.java` file and the libraries must be added to the *Modulepath* instead of to the *Classpath*. Without the `module-info.java` file it would be easier. Therefore, perhaps the **simpler solution would be to delete `module-info.java`** file.

In addition, the `*-source.jar` should be as *Source attachment* a child of the main JAR and the `*-javadoc.jar` is not needed with the source (but if, then as *Javadoc location* child of the main JAR).

Hint: If an error or a warning is shown with a light bulb, go to the line and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and Eclipse will suggest solutions for that problem.